# Stellarium-web canvas navigation through device sensors

Tags: vue.js, device-orientation

I would like to enhance the stellarium-web software, so that it uses the mobile devices sensors to navigate the nightsky.
I managed to put together some js code to get the sensor data, but am at a loss with finding how to incorporate this in stellarium web.
Can anyone point me to the file/function that needs to be called to update the view? So that I can then feed the sensor data into that?
Any help would be much appreciated!

Update: To clarify, I want to build my own version from github.com/Stellarium/stellarium-web-engine, but enhance it with the device sensors.

Alright, update as requested. The following code is a simplified version (I left out the smooting for the values), but shows how I get the sensor data.

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {

  function handleOrientation(event) {
    // read orientation sensors
    var alpha = event.alpha; // rotation z-axis
    var beta = event.beta;   // rotation x-axis
    var gamma = event.gamma; // rotation y-axis

    //console.log("Alpha: " + alpha + ", Beta: " + beta + ", Gamma: " + gamma);
  }

  // add Event Listener
  window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);
}
```

I do think Estus Flask is correct in his last comment, I will try that and get back here with more questions or a solution.
Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what's your case, see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask . Do you build it from https://github.com/Stellarium/stellarium-web-engine , or want to inject a script to https://stellarium-web.org , or what?

Comment: Sorry, sometimes something is self explanatory only to oneself. I updated the question accordingly. Thanks for your input!

Comment: It's unknown what's your code and how it's supposed to interfere with the app. This looks like a proper place to modify https://github.com/Stellarium/stellarium-web-engine/blob/2292cae8bd48ce6581f094625c50c3b1d5e3f2f2/src/js/canvas.js . Probably listen to sensor events similarly to how it's done for mouse, or something else

Comment: Actually the code shouldn't matter. I get values for alpha, beta and gamma (and yes, of course there is an event listener), I am just unsure on how to update the view within the browser with this data.
It feels like stumbling in the dark for me, because I am new with js, and I thought someone with more experience might be able to help out.
Thanks so far.

Comment: What exactly this data is responsible for? It matters because you asked for specific directions. The view is already updating continuously when render function runs, data can possibly be used there. If you get it asynchronously from some api, you possibly can handle it similarly to how mouse/touch input is handled https://github.com/Stellarium/stellarium-web-engine/blob/2292cae8bd48ce6581f094625c50c3b1d5e3f2f2/src/js/canvas.js#L73-L78 . This isn't regular JS project because a considerable amount is C compiled to WASM

Comment: The view is updating continuously when swiping a finger / using the mouse, correct.
Now I want to update the view using the data from the sensors. I get that data from an event listener (as I wrote before), so there are constant updates to the sensor data whenever the device is moved (that means all the time probably).
Maybe this is just too much for me.

Comment: I'd expect it to be done as suggested in the previous comment. You call Module._core_on_mouse inside your listener similarly to how it's already done in mouse listeners

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: provided code as requested, I will try Estus' approach,